# AAC Bluetooth codec on Surface Book 2

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, microsoft-surface

Does Windows 10 and the Surface Book 2 hardware support the AAC Bluetooth codec?

I do notice a rather big difference in sound quality when changing between an iPhone (that do support AAC) and the Surface Book 2.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can NOT stream AAC from Windows 10 over Bluetooth.

I have checked this with the program called "Bluetooth Tweaker" and my "Bose Sound Sport Wireless" which support AAC.